# I need help to improve the drawing of my cylinder to match image of book

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I need help to create a nice image/picture of the cylinder with tikz, something similar to the one below. [image]

Below you can see my current progress, first the image and below the code for it:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[x={(.7cm,-.3cm)}]
\path (1,0,0);
\pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
\path (0,1,0);
\pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
\path (0,0,1);
\pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy * \cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}
\fill[white] (\ct,\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1] -- ++(0,0,8) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
\begin{scope}[every path/.style={ultra thick}]
\draw (0,0,0) circle[radius=1];
\draw[->] (-3,0,0) -- (5,0,0)node[above] {$\sigma_1$};
\draw[->] (0,-3,0) -- (0,5,0)node[above] {$\sigma_2$};
\draw[->] (0,0,-5) -- (0,0,5)node[above] {$\sigma_3$};
\draw[dashed] (0,0,0) ellipse (1.4cm and 0.8cm);
\draw (\ct,\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8);
\draw (-\ct,-\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-8);
\draw (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1];
\draw[dashed] (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem so far is the orientation of the whole cylinder and from the ellipse. If possible the other lines in the picture but is not really necessary.

Any help is greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A first attempt, using 3D.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\raiocilindro{0.5}

 \pgfmathsetmacro\anguloInicio{60}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\nroRaias{10}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\tamanhoSecao{1}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\nroSecoes{8}

\begin{scope}[rotate around y =-30]
\begin{scope}[rotate around y =-45]
\begin{scope}[rotate around z =45]
\begin{scope}[rotate around x =45]
\foreach \x in {0,...,\nroSecoes}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,\tamanhoSecao*\x-0.5*\tamanhoSecao*\nroSecoes)}]
  \draw (0,0) ++(\anguloInicio:\raiocilindro) arc  (\anguloInicio:\anguloInicio-180:\raiocilindro);
\end{scope}
 }
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\nroRaias}{
   \draw (\anguloInicio-\x*180/\nroRaias:\raiocilindro) ++(0,0,-0.5*\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao) -- ++(0,0,\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao);
 }

 \foreach \x in {1,...,\nroRaias}{
  \fill[white] (\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias:\raiocilindro) ++(0,0,-0.5*\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao) arc (\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias:\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias+180/\nroRaias:\raiocilindro) -- ++(0,0,\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao) arc (\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias+18:\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias:\raiocilindro) -- ++(0,0,-\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao);
  \draw (\anguloInicio+\x*180/\nroRaias:\raiocilindro) ++(0,0,-0.5*\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao) -- ++(0,0,\nroSecoes*\tamanhoSecao);
 }
 \foreach \x in {0,...,\nroSecoes}{
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,0,\tamanhoSecao*\x-0.5*\tamanhoSecao*\nroSecoes)}]
  \draw (0,0) ++(\anguloInicio:\raiocilindro) arc  (\anguloInicio:\anguloInicio+180:\raiocilindro);
\end{scope}
 }
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate around x =90 ]
\pgfmathsetmacro\raioB{\raiocilindro*1.414}
 \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse ({\raiocilindro} and {\raioB});
\end{scope}
\end{scope}  
\end{scope} 
\draw[blue,-latex] (-3,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[right] {$\sigma_1$};
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,-3,0) --  (0,3,0) node[right] {$\sigma_3$};
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0,3) -- (0,0,-3) node[right] {$\sigma_2$};
 \node at (3,3,-3) {$\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = \sigma_3$};
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, very nice indeed. I can not say how grateful I am. Maybe one day I can return the favor. Have a very nice day my friend.